# Why do these wav-files behave differently?

Tags: python, numpy, audio, encoding, wav

For my thesis, I am trying to train neural networks to generate sounds. Currently, the output sound is an array of length 64000 (samplerate=16khz). To get a better understanding of how wav-files are encoded, I coded a saw-wave as an array and than converted it into a .wav file via scipy's wavfile.write(). I noticed that when I encode the file via a numpy array, I cannot play the generated file even though they are the same format as a valid wav-file. To fix this, I can load a random audio-file and then change the values in its amplitude array.
This is my first problem and I want to know what is causing the difference between

1. loading a wav-file into a numpy array, altering the array, then saving it
2. creating a numpy array from scratch, encoding via wavfile.write() as a wav file and then saving it (which produces a wav file that cannot be opened).

My second question is how amplitudes work in wav files. Consider following arrays of amplitudes as an example:

```
a = [-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1]
b = [-100, -100, 100, 100, -100, -100, 100, 100]
```

Both arrays represent a square-wave with the same frequency, only that one is louder than the other due to having higher amplitudes. When encoding as a .wav, a is not loud enough to be heard when played at maximum volume. However, my neural network produces .wav files which only have amplitudes in [-1, 1] and still create loud noisy sound. Logically however , they should be the same volume as array a. How do the amplitudes that a wav file is encoded with affect the loudness of the resulting file when it is played?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked specifically with Python or numpy arrays, but the amplitude should reflect the bounds of the encoding. If you are encoding the sounds in 16 bits (most common) the values would range from -32768 to 32767. (a range of 2^16)

It's very common when working with sound to use signed, normalized floats for PCM values for most computations (i.e., ranging from -1 to 1), and then convert to the required bit format of the line at the last stage prior to output.